# Why does this queue behave like this?

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm writing an object which draws from a multiprocessing queue, and I found that when I run this code, I get `data = []`. Whereas if I tell the program to sleep for a little bit at the place denoted, I get `data = [1,2]`, as it should.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
import time

q = Queue()
taken = 0
data = []

for i in [1,2]:
  q.put(i)
# time.sleep(1) making this call causes the correct output 
while not q.empty() and taken < 2:
   try:
     data.append(q.get(timeout=1))
     taken+=1
   except Empty:
     continue
```

**EDIT:**This also happens if there's a print statement before the while loop. This suggests to me that there's something happening with the calls to q.put() that's happening, but I can't find any documentation on this issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce; I added `from multiprocessing import *` and `print(data)` to the top and bottom of your code, respectively, without adding a sleep, and got `[1,2]`. EDIT: Looks like on Python 3 it works, but not on Python 2.

Comment: @ Colonel Thirty Two, try removing the print statement from the top. I've found that that will "fix" the issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for multiprocessing.Queue

> **Note** When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a
> background thread later flushes the pickled data to an underlying
> pipe. This has some consequences which are a little surprising, but
> should not cause any practical difficulties – if they really bother
> you then you can instead use a queue created with a manager.
>
> 1. After
>    putting an object on an empty queue there may be an infinitesimal
>    delay before the queue’s empty() method returns False and get_nowait()
>    can return without raising Queue.Empty.
>    ...

Comment: But I'm not calling get_nowait(), I'm explicitly calling get with a timeout, so I'm not sure how that applies.

Comment: You're calling .empty(), which is explicitly mentioned under point **1**. So you risk not entering your loop at all, depending on how your code vs the background thread operating on the queue is scheduled.